# Use captured variable from request as part of path for next request in IntelliJ HTTP client

Tags: http, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ's HTTP client, how can I capture the output of a request and use part of the request in the path for a subsequent request?

**First Request** - captures the `session_id`.

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8998/sessions
Content-Type: application/json

{"kind": "spark"}

> {% client.global.set("session_id", response.body.json.session_id); %}
```

**Second Request** - How do I use the capture `session_id` in the path of this request?

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8998/sessions/{{session_id}}/statements
Content-Type: application/json

{"code": "123"}

###
Errors with:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 31.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing everything right apart from reading from the response body - probably, `session_id` doesn't get the value you expected it to get.

To confirm that, you can add `client.log(client.global.get("session_id"));` to the response handler script of the second request (removing the var from the URL first) and then check the Response Handler tab.

Comment: Yep, the problem was there was no `json` field on `body`.